# Cannot add, remove nor access mapped share "Element not found" in Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8, file-sharing, cifs

A standard user on my Windows 8.1-64 cannot remove a mapped drive. Tried command line and explorer. Tried run as admin. "Element not found" everywhere.

```
C:\Windows\system32>net use x: /delete
The network connection could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.
```

In registry there is nothing under the users mapped drives, only keys like this:

```
HKEY_USERS\user\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\{E6FC8523-44D0-477A-B4C2-F35C7FDE04E3}
```

The share was created for all users and when I create a new user the mapped drive is there and working. Problem occurred when the file server was restarted and the user could not access the share. I tried deleting the share from the user. I tried accessing the share directly. Tried creating a new one. Element not found.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across your question while researching a related problem of my own.
You may wish to check out the following link:
http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/CA516897BD8A80B8862578A90056DFD7
It explains that when you use the "run as admin" option, you are actually running under an account that is different from the account on which the drive was originally mapped.